# Swift 5.1: what is the correct code to hide UIButton?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have the new Xcode 11.4.1 with what I think is swift 5.1.

I am trying to hide a button (UIButton) with the known `button.hidden=true` / `button.isHidden=true` / `button.alpha=0` but none seem to work.
I get the error 
Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'isHidden'
same for hidden and alpha.

The button is defined:

@IBAction func submittedk(_ sender: UIButton){
code}

What is the correct code to hide buttons in this version? Thanks

Comment: Please share some code referencing your problem

Comment: Not enough information. How the button is defined?
`isHidden` is a valid `UIButton` property, Swift 5.1 or not... So most likely you are using a reference that is recognized as generic object, not `UIButton`

Comment: Yes, sorry. The definition is:   @IBAction func submittedk(_ sender: UIButton)

Comment: The button is the `sender`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You need to add IBOutlet of a button, not only an IBAction.
And then apply:

> buttonOutlet.isHidden = true